# check for the value and then save the index into a key that can contains many indexes/values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would like to load the list and then find the similar item within the list for its index number. I would then create a dictionary to store these index number. 
The index number should be stored within the same dictionary.

My code:

```
a = ["a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "r" , "g" , "h" , "f" , "a", "b" ,"c" , "c" , "c" , "f", "f" , "a" , "a" , "h" ]

aa = []
index = []
for x in a:
    aa.append(x)
    dd = {}
    if x in aa:
        dd[x] = [a.index(x)]
    index.append(dd)

print(index)
```

Current output:

```
[{'a': [0]}, {'b': [1]}, {'c': [2]}, {'d': [3]}, {'r': [4]}, {'g': [5]}, {'h': [6]}, {'f': [7]}, {'a': [0]}, {'b': [1]}, {'c': [2]}, {'c': [2]}, {'c': [2]}, {'f': [7]}, {'f': [7]}, {'a': [0]}, {'a': [0]}, {'h': [6]}]
```

For example:

Expected output:

```
[{'a': [0, 8, 15, 16]}, {'b': [1, 9]}, {'c': [2,10,11,12]}, {'d': [3]}, {'r': [4]}, {'g': [5]}, {'h': [6,17]}, {'f': [7,13,14]}]
```

Or the expected output can be something like this too if possible:

```
[[0, 8, 15, 16],[1, 9],[2,10,11,12],[3],[4],[5],[6,17],[7,13,14]]
```

I tried many other ways but it keeps saving differently and not to the same key in the dictionary for multiple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collection.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = ["a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "r" , "g" , "h" , "f" , "a", "b" ,"c" , "c" , "c" , "f", "f" , "a" , "a" , "h" ]
d = defaultdict(list)

for i, v in enumerate(a):   #enumerate to get index
    d[v].append(i)

print(d)
print(d.values())
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [0, 8, 15, 16], 'c': [2, 10, 11, 12], 'b': [1, 9], 'd': [3], 'g': [5], 'f': [7, 13, 14], 'h': [6, 17], 'r': [4]})
[[0, 8, 15, 16], [2, 10, 11, 12], [1, 9], [3], [5], [7, 13, 14], [6, 17], [4]]
```